# Как сохранить/восстановить состояние кнопки после обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript

У меня возникли проблемы с сохранением статуса кнопки после обновления страницы. Были попытки использовать localStorage, как показано ниже, но это не работает:

```js
const toggleSectionText = (section, btnText1, btnText2, parText1, parText2) => {
    const btn = section.querySelector('input')
    const par = section.querySelector('p')

    if (btn.value === btnText1) {
        btn.value = btnText2
        par.textContent = parText2
    } else {
        btn.value = btnText1
        par.textContent = parText1
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('Открыть форточку') === null)
        localStorage.setItem('Открыть форточку', false);
    })
    const window1 = document.querySelector('#window');
    window1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem(
            'Открыть форточку',
            localStorage.getItem('Открыть форточку') === 'false'
                ? true
                : false
        );
        toggleSectionText(window1, 'Закрыть форточку', 'Открыть форточку', 
    'Форточка открыта', 'Форточка закрыта')});
```

Comment: А в каком месте Вы используете значение, сохранённое в local storage, для восстановления состояния кнопки/параграфа?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('Открыть форточку') === 'false' ? true : false` не имеет смысла. достаточно `localStorage.getItem('Открыть форточку') === 'false'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. вы выложили только фрагмент кода, то даю решение разбив на части. Первым делом, необходимо инициализировать интерфейс исходя из состояния указанного в `localStorage`. Для этого вам нужно модифицировать функцию обратного вызова `load` следующим образом:

```js
const window1 = document.querySelector('#window'); // селектор поднимем выше

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const isOpen = localStorage.getItem('Открыть форточку') === 'true'
    ? true
    : false;
    
  const btn = window1.querySelector('input')
  const par = window1.querySelector('p')
  // инициализация интерфейсных элементов
  if (isOpen) {
    btn.value = 'Закрыть форточку'
    par.textContent = 'Форточка открыта'
  } else {
    btn.value = 'Открыть форточку'
    par.textContent = 'Форточка закрыта'
  }
})
```

Также нужно изменить выставление значения в `localStorage` в функции обратного вызова `click`:

```js
window1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.setItem(
    'Открыть форточку',
    // заменим проверку на строку true. Все что отличное от 'true' будет false 
    localStorage.getItem('Открыть форточку') === 'true' ? 
    false :
    true
  );
  toggleSectionText(window1, 'Закрыть форточку', 'Открыть форточку',
    'Форточка открыта', 'Форточка закрыта')
});
```

Замечу, лучше проверять `=== 'true'`, т.к. это покрывает любые иные значения из localStorage отличных от `'true'` и избавляет от необходимости делать проверку на `== null` и `=== 'false'`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А если мне нужно сохранять статус у 8 кнопок, у этого  же кода нужно поменять название переменных?

Answer (score -1):

```
const toggleSectionText = (section, btnText1, btnText2, parText1, parText2) => {
    const btn = section.querySelector('input')
    const par = section.querySelector('p')

    if (btn.value === btnText1) {
        btn.value = btnText2
        par.textContent = parText2
        localStorage.setItem('open', true)
    } else {
        btn.value = btnText1
        par.textContent = parText1
        localStorage.setItem('open', false)
    }
}
```

и уже это суете в слушатель события клика.
а далее проверяете значение поля `open` из `localStorage` и расставляете нужные значения. не забудьте про дефолтное состояние, когда `localStorage` пуст!

Comment: И каким образом это работает? Зачем очищать всё локальное хранилище?

Comment: @XelaNimed незачем. я переписывал. остался старый код. как работает написано далее